# jQuery somehow adding spaces to output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a script to dynamically create anchor tags and links to a specific element. However, when I output  the anchor text, it adds a bunch of spaces between the hash and the text.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.accordion h2').each(function(){
        var thisText = $(this).text();
        var anchorText = thisText.replace(/ /g, "-");
        var anchorLink = '<a name="' + anchorText + '"></a>';
        var anchorTextFull = '<a href="#' + anchorText + '">' + thisText + '</a>';
        $(this).before(anchorLink);
        $(this).after(anchorTextFull);
    });
});
```

This code outputs the following for the anchorTextFull variable:

```
    <a href="#     foo-bar">Foo Bar</a>
```

Where are these spaces coming from?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery includes a trim function that you can use to remove extra whitespace at the beginning or end of a string:

```
var thisText =  $.trim($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 4):

This problem is actually caused by HTML behaving differently then JQuery.  In HTML, spaces and extra lines don't matter.

In HTML, these 2 examples are visually the same when rendered to the page:

```
<div id="vendor">Barracuda</div>
```

and

```
<div id="vendor">
    Barracuda
</div>
```

However when you use JQuery's .Text() method, they yield different results.

```
<div id="vendor">Barracuda</div>

$('#vendor').text()  // equals  "Barracuda"
```

But this is very different:

```
<div id="vendor">
    Barracuda
</div>

$('#vendor').text()  // equals  "           Barracuda           "
```

Thus the need to .trim() the results if you can't tailor the HTML, or just want to play it safe.

```
var thisText = $.trim($(this).text());
```

[JSFiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/usy8F/)

Answer (score 0):

These are probably coming from the `$(this).text()`. These could be the new line characters within `h2` tags. Do an `alert("'" + $(this).text() + "'" )` to confirm.